# How to center an image to the center of an image it sits above in swift

Tags: swift

I have a function which programatically adds an image over the top of another image. My problem is that the image that sits on top does not center properly.. it sits slightly off center. What am I doing wrong?

```
    func imageCheck() {
        if pickedImage != nil {
            addPainting()
        } else {
            print("image did not come back from uploadVC.")
        }
    }
    
    
    func addPainting() {
        let pickedImageView = UIImageView(image: pickedImage)
        pickedImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: 150, height: 150)
        pickedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        pickedImageView.center = userPickedRoom.center // userPickedRoom is the image that sits beneath pickedImage
        view.addSubview(pickedImageView)
    }
}
```

Comment: You should activate anchors of pickedImageView.

Comment: That is enough to know for solving your problem. Check [this source](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/basics/layout-anchors/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**tldr**: it's not cool to add subviews without activation of constraints because any UI changes (for example, device rotation) make call unpredictable behavior of added views without activated constraints.

**In fact**, your approach consists of the next steps:

1. You initialize some view and prepare its preferences programmatically.
2. Define a hard-coded frame without guarantees in the next future.
3. And just added it.

Instead of hard coding the frame, it's better to define the frame automatically based on constraints. You might do this like below:

1. Initialize and then prepare all the preferences for your subview.
2. Add it to the parent of the view.
3. And define constraints, then activate them:

```
func addPainting() {
    let pickedImageView = UIImageView(image: pickedImage)
    pickedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    view.addSubview(pickedImageView)
    pickedImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        pickedImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userPickedRoom.centerXAnchor),
        pickedImageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: userPickedRoom.centerYAnchor),
        pickedImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
        pickedImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150)
    ])
}
```